# flake8 in elpy does not recognize per-file-ignores

Tags: elpy

I'm using the excellent Elpy. I have with a Python project with a `.flake8` config file at the top of the project source tree. I have this content in the `.flake8` file:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E251, E501, E303, E271, E221, E226
per-file-ignores =
    admin/export-data:E241,E304
```

(`export-data` is a Python script in the subdirectory `admin/` of the project.) Elpy running Flymake clearly reads the configuration file and correctly reads the globally-ignored error codes: I can see the effect of adding or removing error code values in the `ignore` line. However, the per-file settings for the file `admin/export-data` are not being recognized. At first, I thought the problem was the file path, so I tried variations such as just `export-data`, using the absolute path to `export-data`, and so on, and nothing seems to change the behavior: the `per-file-ignores` setting is itself ignored.  Yet it works if I run `flake8` in a terminal, outside of Emacs.

Is there a trick to getting the `flake8`/Elpy/Flymake combination to recognize the `per-file-ignores` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flymake` doesn't call `flake8` directly. Instead it builds a [`python3` command-line](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/55f25fd98abc145c0c464756504132c271f0f039/flycheck.el#L10560) and (if I remember correctly) feeds it the buffer contents via stdin. Naturally there's no filename in this case, but `flymake` handles this by using `flake8`'s `--stdin-display-name=` option. According to [this issue at the `flymake` repo](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1644), this works in the case of simple filenames, but there is apparently a [`flake8` bug in recognizing relative paths](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/693).

tl;dr:
It sorta works, but in your case it's not working because of an outstanding `flake8` bug.